# Lync: CaptureVideowindow and RenderVideoWindow always null

Tags: video-capture

My application is to incorporate Lync communication (Lync 2013) into our application and
for this i am using windows forms application. I am using the code which i have downloaded from [msdn][1] site. I got the issue with the VideoWindows (CaptureVideoWindow, RenderVideoWindow) of the AVModality's VideoChannel: They are always null, even after successfully calling BeginStart. The connection is established and audio channel is also working fine, but the video is not capturing into my own window.
I am using Lync 2013 in UISuppression mode too.

getting null in VideoChannel.RenderVideoWindow and VideoChannel.CaptureVideowindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solve the issue, now it is working good,
what the problem is , in previous i used
lync basic version: 15.0.4420.1.17
lync SDk: 15.0.4517.1004
so, the video is not displayed in our own window, then i updated Lync basic version to 15.0.4517.1504 and the problem is solved.
so, the basic version of Lync is always greater than the version of Lync SDK we are using in our system.
You can download updated version from here
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2817621

and see the solution in the following link too
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/07ee768a-d308-4dad-95ea-837c95bcadd2/uisuppression-videowindowowner-raises-generic-com-exception-0x800706f7

Comment: i have the same problem and it is fixed thank you.
do you have a link for the SDK v 15.0.4517.1004 since i have the same issue with ApplicationSharing modality it always return null.

Comment: @Anas You can download the SDK v 15.0.4517.1004 from the below link https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xxsg41wkqzneux/lyncsdk_2013.exe  If you have any issues please let me know